# read() doesn't block on empty FIFOs opened without O_NONBLOCK flag

Tags: c, linux, pipe

[**`pipe(7)`**](https://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe) says:

> If a process attempts to read from an empty pipe, then read(2) will block until data is available. If a process attempts to write to a full pipe (see below), then write(2) blocks until sufficient data has been read from the pipe to allow the write to complete. Nonblocking I/O is possible by using the fcntl(2) F_SETFL operation to enable the O_NONBLOCK open file status flag.

Below I have two simple C programs compiled on linux with gcc:

**`reader.c`**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define STACKBUF_SIZE 128
#define FIFO_PATH "/home/bogdan/.imagedata"

signed int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int fifo_fd = open(FIFO_PATH, O_RDONLY); // blocking... - notice no O_NONBLOCK flag
    if (fifo_fd != -1) {
        fprintf(stdout, "open() call succeeded\n");
    }

    while (1) {
        char buf[STACKBUF_SIZE] = {0};
        ssize_t bread = read(fifo_fd, buf, STACKBUF_SIZE);
        fprintf(stdout, "%d - %s\n", bread, buf);
        sleep(1);
    }

    close(fifo_fd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**`writer.c`**:

```
#define STACKBUF_SIZE 128
#define FIFO_PATH "/home/bogdan/.imagedata"
#define DATA "data"

int main(void) {
    int fifo_fd = open(FIFO_PATH, O_WRONLY); // blocks until reader opens on the reader end, however we always first open the reader so...
    if(fifo_fd != -1) {
        ssize_t bwritten = write(fifo_fd, DATA, 5);
        fprintf(stdout, "writer wrote %ld bytes\n", bwritten);
    }
    
    close(fifo_fd);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

The files are compiled into two separate binaries with `gcc writer.c -Og -g -o ./writer`, same for the reader.

From the shell I first execute the reader binary, and as expected, the initial `open()` call blocks until I also execute the writer. I then execute the writer, whose `open()` call immediately succeeds and it writes 5 bytes to the FIFO (which are correctly displayed by the reader), after which it closes the fd, **leaving the FIFO empty** (?).

However, **the following `read()` calls in the while loop of the reader don't block at all, and instead just return 0**.

Unless I am missing something (I probably am) this is in clash with the semantics outlined by the pipe(7) manpage, as the FIFO fd was open without the `O_NONBLOCK` flag both in the reader and the writer.

Comment: Joseph has pointed out that this is not what the documentation says, and moreover it wouldn't make sense: the point of blocking is to wait for something to happen (here, data being available).  When the other end of the pipe has been closed, data will never become available, and so your semantics would leave the program stuck forever, which couldn't possibly be a useful way to handle the situation.

Comment: The actual semantics also conveniently mimic what happens when you read from a regular file, which helps make the pipe transparent and ensures that most programs can automatically handle piped input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section of the manual that you quoted only applies to pipes with open writers. Two paragraphs down, it says this:

> If all file descriptors referring to the write end of a pipe have been closed, then an attempt to read(2) from the pipe will see end-of-file (read(2) will return 0).